# Regression analysis throwing random data

Tags: r, forecasting

The following is my data,

```
day       sum
2015-03-05   44           
2015-03-06   46           
2015-03-06   48           
2015-03-07   48           
2015-03-08   58           
2015-03-09   58           
2015-03-10   66           
2015-03-11   68           
2015-03-12   85           
2015-03-13   94           
2015-03-14   98           
2015-03-15  102           
2015-03-16  102           
2015-03-17  104           
2015-03-17  114
```

The type of variables used are as follows,

```
typeof(x)
[1] "list"

typeof(x$day)
[1] "double"

typeof(x$sum)
[1] "integer"

class(x$day)
[1] "Date"
```

I want to predict, at what date, a particular sum would be attained.

The following are my findings,

When I use regression analysis,

```
q<-lm((as.POSIXct(x$day,"%Y-%m-%d"))~x$sum)
> predict(q,data.frame(x$sum==3000))
```

It is throwing some random values as follows,

```
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8 
1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 
         9         10         11         12         13         14         15         16 
1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 
        17         18         19         20         21         22         23         24 
1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 
        25         26         27         28         29         30         31         32 
1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 
        33         34         35         36         37         38         39         40 
1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426062187 1426074330 1426086474 1426086474 1426147192
```

When I use ts(x), the values of the dates are changing as follows,

```
day

16464              

16465              

16466

16467

16468

16469

16470

16471

16472
```

When I use ets, following is the output,

```
fit <- ets(x)
Error in ets(ana) : y should be a univariate time series
```

Can anybody please suggest what mistake I am doing here and why I am not able to use any models here?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you want to be predicting date as a function of sum and not vice versa?

Comment: It is on both the ways. May be the way you said also, I need to find when a particular count will be achieved.

Comment: the statement `predict(q,data.frame(x$sum==3000))` does not make sense to me.  are you trying to say something like `predict(q, newdata=data.frame(sum=3000))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying values of dates in R are numeric values. What you're seeing are not random values, but the numeric values of `day` for two different date formats.

If `day` is in POSIXct format, then the value is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970. If `day` is in Date format, then the value is the number of days since January 1, 1970. For example:

```
x$day = as.POSIXct(x$day)
as.numeric(x$day)

[1] 1425542400 1425628800 1425628800 1425715200 ...


as.numeric(as.Date(x$day))

[1] 16499 16500 16500 16501 16502 ...
```

Here's some code to do the regression and plot it in date format. For consistency, you have to be careful to make sure the origin (reference time) and time zone are always the same:

```
# Set x$day to POSIXct format, with time zone UTC
x$day = as.POSIXct(x$day, tz="UTC")

# Regression model predicting day from sum
q<-lm(day ~ sum, data=x)

# Plot day vs. sum and add regression line and a point prediction
plot(x$sum, x$day, las=1, ylab="", xlab="Sum", 
     xlim=c(40, 120), ylim=c(min(x$day), predict(q, data.frame(sum=120))))
lines(x$sum, as.POSIXct(predict(q), origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC", tz="UTC"),
      col="red")
points(120, predict(q, data.frame(sum=120)), pch=16, col="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand it better. Is there a way we can change that back to dates and use it for prediction?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is working for me. Do you know, how to get the values from the graph?

Comment: Those are just the values you plotted. For example, the points for `lines(x$sum, as.POSIXct(predict(q), origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC", tz="UTC"), col="red")` are just `x$sum` and `as.POSIXct(predict(q), origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC", tz="UTC")`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I want to get the date which is plotted in the graph as an value and store it in a variable.

Comment: The graph code in my answer already gives that to you. You can store any of those vectors as a separate object or combine any of them into a new data frame of predicted and/or measured values.

Comment: Oh my bad. Yeah Thanks I found it out. Just asking for knowledge purpose. How do we test the accuracy of the analysis? and Is there a way we can improve the accuracy of prediction?

Comment: Lots of ways, but probably better to ask a new question on that over at [crossvalidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), since that's more of a methodology question than a coding question.